# Insert Datarow in a desired position In Wpf DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I insert a Row in a desired position in Wpf DataGrid?

I have tried:

```
GridCollection.Insert(2, (new ColumnCollection()))
```

In order to insert it at the 3rd index. Where GridCollection Is the `ItemSource` of the `DataGrid`. But it's adding row on the last of the Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, we generally work with *data* rather than *UI elements*. Therefore, to do this in data, we'd just need to do this:

```
DataBoundCollection.Insert(2, newItem);
```

If you have correctly implemented the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your view model or code behind (or used a `DependencyProperty` in a `UserControl` or `Window` code behind) and data bound a collection of items to your `DataGrid.ItemsSource`, then the above code will result in a new item being added into the `DataGrid` in the third from top position:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataBoundCollection}" ... />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

I have no idea what you're doing, but I'm guessing that you have over complicated the situation. Ignore your current code and put this into a new project and then you will see that it works perfectly:

The XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<int> numbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
public ObservableCollection<int> Numbers
{
    get { return numbers; }
    set { numbers = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Numbers"); }
}

...

private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Numbers.Insert(2, 10);
}
```

In the constructor:

```
Numbers = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Now when you double click on the `DataGrid`, you'll see new rows being added at position 3, not at the beginning or end.

Comment: Hi Sheridan ,
    You mean to say for that GridCollection/DataBoundCollection property I have to use OnPropertyChange("GridCollection/DataBoundCollection") method which is Inherited from INotifyPropertyChanged?
If It is so Still It Is adding row in the bottom of the grid
Thanks
Sushmit

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. I was saying that if you work with *data* objects instead of *UI* objects, then you can add a *data* item into a *data* collection that is data bound to a UI collection control and the UI control will show the change.

Comment: GridCollection Observable<DataCollection> GridCollection {get;set;}
DataCollection Class having some data properties.....

So At the time of adding Row In a specific Index, I was doing 
GridCollection.Insert(2, new DataCollection(){ prop1, prop2, prop3})
Allready 8 Rows are there.
So instead of adding 3rd position it's adding last position.

Comment: So instead of adding 3rd position it's adding last position.

<DataGrid ItemsSource={"Binding GridCollection , Mode=two way"}...../>

Comment: Thanks A lot  the above code is working fine. even if we pass Some class instead of int its working fine. But In my case I am passing different type of column collection in the class. e.g Checkbox, datetimecontrol, textbox etc, so that different bindings in every columns.

Comment: Well, don't do that then. In WPF, we manipulate *data*, not *UI elements*. I have no idea what you're trying to achieve by doing that, but I'm pretty sure that you're doing it the wrong way.

Comment: If I perform the GridCollection.Insert(2,new DataCollection) in viewmodel constructor then its working fine.
But I have decalred button delegate command in the constructor and call the execute method outside of the constructor & use GridCollection.Insert(2,new DataCollection) in that method outside of the constructor...then its adding at the last of that grid